# How to minimize the ringer and alert volume programmatically in iOS using Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

If it is not possible then is there any Apple documentation for it?

Comment: Your question title grammar wrong so edits first your question.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

please try using this piece of code:

```
func setSystemVolume(volume: Float) {
    let volumeView = MPVolumeView()

    for view in volumeView.subviews {
        if (NSStringFromClass(view.classForCoder) == "MPVolumeSlider") {
            let slider = view as! UISlider
            slider.setValue(volume, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried above solution but it's not working for ringer and alert volume. I think using MPVolumeView we can change music player volume not the os sound.